# Javacscript/jQuery replace content in element

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to replace the content in an element, but nothing is happening. Not even getting an error back.

```
var total = 15;
$('.totals div h3 span').replaceWith("<p class='totaal'>" + total +" TOTAAL</p>");
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/MennoK/pen/QpjNPZ

Comment: there is definitely an error in your code `Uncaught TypeError: selectors.size is not a function`

Comment: make sure $('.totals div h3 span') actually returns elements. When I tried it in your codepen I didn't see anything, which would explain why nothing is happening and you're not getting errors.

Comment: When you decide to publish some code on SO, try to avoid codepen. It's very slow and highly unreadable. There's a feature called 'code snippet' on SO. Use it instead.

Comment: in your codepen total is misspelled - `totaal` - is it the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the function `.replaceWith()` by `.html()`

e.g.

```
$('.totals div h3 span').html("<p class='totaal'>" + total +" TOTAAL</p>");
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZvEjV

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.totals div.wpb_wrapper h3 span').replaceWith("<span style='color: #ffffff;' class='tobtaal'>222 TOTAAL</span>");
```

try it!
the text is not seen because is black, also there are two divs